# Significant figures in conversion factors?

Tags: significant-figures

> Example: I have $\pu{64 cm^{3}}$ of milk. How much is that in gallons?

When I use the conversion factors $\frac{\pu{1 mL}}{\pu{1 cm^3}}$
$\frac{\pu{1L}}{\pu{1000 mL}}$ $\frac{\pu{1.0567 qt}}{\pu{1 L}}$ $\frac{\pu{1 gal}}{\pu{4 qt}}$.

I know the final answer should only have two significant figures, but how many significant figures should the intermediate conversion factors have?

I have heard that:

- conversion factors should have one more sig fig than the least precise measurement. (*So three in this case*)
- But I also heard that we shouldn't round anything until the end. 
  (*So use all 5, and round after conversions are complete*)

The reason why I got confused is because of my textbook:

> [image]

Comment: check your conversion factor. $1 \text{cm}^3$ is a milliliter which is much much less than a quart.

Comment: With a modern calculator, I wouldn't round anything until the end. When doing calculations with a slide rule or log tables, then things were a bit different.

Comment: This is case dependent. You need to realize what kind of mathematical object are you deal with.

Comment: @MaxW, so is my textbook wrong in rounding in this example?

Comment: @ user1420303 In the attached textbook example, they rounded an exact conversion factor. But when I did the math on my own and didnt round untill the end, I came up with a slightly different answer. Does that mean we are both right?

Comment: eromod - Your textbook is wrong to imply that there is any particular rounding method that will always yield the "right" result. Rounding has always caused problems. The overall point is just that you have to realize that rounding will cause problems and be careful. There isn't any magic procedure.

Comment: @Max, how would you do it?

Comment: As I said, if I had a calculator, I wouldn't round anything until the end. If I had to do all the calculations by hand, then I'd be inclined to round intermediate values. I'm not going to multiple two 8-digit numbers by hand and then round to 2 digits.

Comment: So to conclude: round conversion factors only if you dont have a calculator because its tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use significant figures as much as you can in intermediate conversion factors,and then round off the final answer to two significant figures,using more significant figures in intermediate conversion factors will lead to a accurate answer.
I let you conclude.

Comment: that was my initial impression too, but have a look at my textbook example I attached.

Comment: you should  use as much as sig.fig.,i have seen many examples and solved many exersises regarding this topic,and have never seen rounding off before the final answer unless significant figures are too much and cannot be taken under arithmatic operations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your conversion factor came from as it is incorrect but regarding the correct factor:
Because the inch is defined using the metre, and the gallon defined using the inch, there is an *exact* conversion between them—1 US gallon is exactly 3.785411784 L.
Thus, like any exact quantity or conversion factor, we treat the gallon to litre conversion factor as having infinite significant figures.
Because we have defined it exactly, there is no implicit uncertainty in the number.
There are other conversion factors that are not exact and do actually have uncertainties, but for most practical purposes, these have far more significant figures than a normal measured quantity.
See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38065/do-all-conversion-factors-have-an-infinite-number-of-sigfigs?rq=1) for more details.

Comment: conversion factors were wrong, I updated them. But what is the conclusion though? How many sig figs should I use? That link says I should look it up in the CRC Handbook. That what you recommend too?

Comment: As my answer says, the conversion factor is exact.

Comment: So if my measured quantity is $\ 64 cm^{3}$ , how many significant figures should I use in the qt/L conversion? All of them because its an *exact* conversion? Or just three sig figs (one more that the two I have to work with)

Comment: @eromod The conversion factor is only exact if you use that exact conversion factor. For example, an inch is defined as 2.54 cm. If you use that number, it has infinite precision. However, if you say "ahh, 2.5 is close enough" then the conversion factor only has 2 significant digits. Likewise here. If you use the exact conversion factor, there's infinite precision. If you round it, it has the rounded amount of precision.

Comment: @ R.M. But in my textbook, they rounded the conversion factor...I added a screenshot